# SQL Server 2008 need a simple method to get customer name, adress and so on from kundeliste

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT TOP (1) Ordreliste.OrdreID, Ordreliste.KundeID, 
Ordreliste.OrdreDato, Ordreliste.Navn, Ordreliste.Farve
FROM Ordreliste INNER JOIN Kundeliste ON Ordreliste.KundeID = Kundeliste.KundeID 
ORDER BY Ordreliste.OrdreDato DESC
```

I need a simple method to get customer name, address and so on from `kundeliste` and can it be put into the existing method??

Comment: Ordreliste have to be Orderliste?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
SELECT TOP (1) Ordreliste.OrdreID, Ordreliste.KundeID, Ordreliste.OrdreDato,
Ordreliste.Navn, Ordreliste.Farve, Kundeliste.CustomerName, Kundeliste.CustomerAddress
FROM Ordreliste INNER JOIN Kundeliste ON Ordreliste.KundeID = Kundeliste.KundeID 
ORDER BY Ordreliste.OrdreDato DESC
```

If you are lookng to get customer name and customer address from Kundeliste table, where Joining condition meets, then you simply just needs to mention the column names in the select clause.